# get_page() unlike Loop returns the post content without html tags. How can I fix this?

Tags: loop, tags, html, pages

get_page() unlike Loop returns the post content without html tags. I need tags. How can I fix this?

I don't want to change wysiwyg editor, here is the bad solution http://wordpress.org/support/topic/preserve-html-with-get_pages

Comment: Please edit the question, instead of leaving comments to it.

Comment: what is your full code to output the content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are getting the page content like so:

```
$page_id = 1;
$page = get_page($page_id);
$content = $page->post_content;
echo $content;
```

If thats the case then you can run the content through the `the_content` filter:

```
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

The will process the content as if it was run through `the_content()` function.